# How to make a plot showing mean, SD, min and % based on a normal distribution in R language?

Tags: ggplot2

Based on a normal distribution with the following parameters:

```
mean_value_VO2 <- 250.57
min_value_VO2 <- 128.16
sd_value_VO2 <- 351.74
Proportion (%) under the curve=63.6%
```

I wish to make a plot as Figure 6 in the paper at "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5985399/#SM1".

I tried the following codes

```
# Create a vector of x values
x <- seq(min_value_VO2, mean_value_VO2 + 2*sd_value_VO2, length = 27)

# Calculate the y values using the normal distribution function
y <- dnorm(x, mean = mean_value_VO2, sd = sd_value_VO2)

# Plot the curve
plot(x, y, type = "l", xlab = "X-axis label", ylab = "Y-axis label")
```

, but it's not what as expected. In particular, I wish to label all the above numbers (mean=250.57, min=128.16 and sd=351.74; and proportion which is the area under the curve= 63.6%.

Therefore, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the `ggplot2` package to generate your graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

It requires to gather the `x` and `y` variables in a dataframe first:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(-800, 1300, 1),
                 y = dnorm(seq(-800, 1300, 1), mean = mean_value_VO2, sd = sd_value_VO2))
```

And a plot such as the one you're aiming for can be generated as follows:

```
# Indicate the dataset and to which axis assign each variable
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  # Add a line
  geom_line() +
  # Add the area for values above the min with 50% opacity
  geom_area(data = df[df$x >= min_value_VO2, ], alpha = .5) +
  # Add the segment for the min value
  geom_segment(aes(x = min_value_VO2, xend = min_value_VO2,
                   y = 0, yend = y[match(round(min_value_VO2), x)])) +
  # Add the segment for the mean value
  geom_segment(aes(x = mean_value_VO2, xend = mean_value_VO2,
                   y = 0, yend = y[match(round(mean_value_VO2), x)]), 
               linetype = "dashed") +
  # Add the annotation for the mean/sd values
  annotate("text", x = mean_value_VO2, y = 0.00125,
           label = paste("Mean =", mean_value_VO2, "\n", "SD =", sd_value_VO2)) +
  # Add the annotation for the min value
  annotate("text", x = min_value_VO2, y = -.0001, label = paste("Min =", min_value_VO2)) + 
  # Add the annotation for the proportion under the curve
  annotate("text", x = 450, y = .0005,label = "Proportion:\n 63%") +
  # Apply the "void" preset theme
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful guides and codes. It's really what I expected.